# How to decorate a test to xfail a specific case with multiple parametrization?

Tags: python, pytest

Is there a way in `pytest` to **xfail** a test when a specific parametrization condition is met?
Note the parametrization is on `fixture`, not using `mark.parametrize`.

```py
from pytest import fixture, xfail

@fixture(params=['a', 'b'])
def setup_1(request):
    return request.param

@fixture(params=['x', 'y'])
def setup_2(request):
    return request.param

@xfail() # Something here ??
def test_something(setup_1, setup_2):
    ...  # Asserrt something
```

I would like to modify the example above so the test is **xfail** when, for example `setup_1='a'` and `setup_2='x'`?
I know one option according to [pytest documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/skipping.html#xfail-mark-test-functions-as-expected-to-fail) is to just use a condition inside the test:

```
def test_something(setup_1, setup_2):
    if setup_1 == 'a' and setup_2 == 'x':
        pytest.xfail("failing configuration (but should work)")
    else:
        ...  # Assert something
```

However, I was wondering if there might be a more readable way using decorators.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is not possible to do easily what you intend to do with parameters coming from multiple parametrized `fixture`s. However and even if it's not exactly what you intend to do, it's worth highlighting that you can parametrize `xfail` as stated [in the documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/skipping.html#skip-xfail-with-parametrize).

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    ("setup_1", "setup_2"), [
        pytest.param("a", "x", marks=pytest.mark.xfail(reason="some bug")),
        ("a", "y"),
        ("b", "x"),
        ("b", "y"),
    ]
)
def test_something(setup_1, setup_2):
    print(f"{setup_1}, {setup_2}")
```

Unfortunately and as far as I know, it does not work with parametrized `fixture`s. So in conclusion, if you need to have parameters coming from fixtures, your option (condition in the test method) seems to be the best solution.